# Enumerating a view's NSLayoutConstraints in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

```
   [self.view.constraints enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ((constraint.firstItem == view) && (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeTop)) {
            constraint.constant = -200;
        }
    }];
```

In Objective-C, I would be able to enumerate a view's constraints and adjust the constraints accordingly, but in Swift I'm having difficulty figuring out to do the equivalent.

here is my attempt at applying the code in swift:

```
   for (index, value) in enumerate(view.constraints()) {
        var constraint = value as NSLayoutConstraint
        if value.firstItem? = view  {
            constraint.constant = -200;
        }

    }
```

I get a compiler error stating "Type '[AnyObject!' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence' on the first line of this code.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: On which line are you getting this error?

Comment: @reecon the first line - `for (index, value) in enumerate(view.constraints()) {
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `constraints()` returns `[AnyObject]!` which is optional so you need to unwrap `view.constraints()!` before use.So unwrap it  Use below code

```
    for (index, value) in enumerate(view.constraints()!) {
        var constraint = value as NSLayoutConstraint
        if value.firstItem? = view  {
            constraint.constant = -200;
        }

    }
```

Also you cannot assign `firstItem` as it is readonly property.I think you want to compare it.So use `if value.firstItem! as UIView == self.view`.So use `

```
 for (index, value) in enumerate(view.constraints()!) {
        var constraint = value as NSLayoutConstraint
        if value.firstItem! as UIView == self.view {
            constraint.constant = -200;
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks for your response, in your code i am getting this compiler error "Cannot assign to the result of this expression" on the line 
`if value.firstItem? = view`

Comment: edited answer.I think you want  to use comparision ` if value.firstItem! as UIView == self.view`