# getting NSLayoutConstraints associated view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I trying to loop through a views constraints.

I added to view1: top, trailing, leading and height constraints.

top, trailing and leading are to the main ViewControllers view.

if i loop through view1's constraints i only see the height constraint.

```
for constraint in view1.constraints {
    print(constraint)
}
```

> NSLayoutConstraint:0x6180000968a0 UIView:0x7fae6b409dd0.height == 146   (active)

so i looped through its superviews constraints (the ViewControllers main view) and i got lots of constraints some of them are associated with view1.

```
for constraint in view1.superview?.constraints {
    print(constraint)
}
```

> NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000096670 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fae6b409dd0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fae6b40a180 )
>
> NSLayoutConstraint:0x6180000974d0 H:[UIView:0x7fae6b409dd0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fae6b40a180 )
>
> NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000097520 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fae6b409dd0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fae6b40a180 )

and i get a few more that i dont care about.

So my problem is that i want to loop through all of view1's superviews constraints and get only the ones that are associated with it.

In this example `UIView:0x7fae6b409dd0` is view1.

But i cant figure out how to get that property.

Thanks

---

If i print out `constraint.firstAnchor` i get some more information but still cant get the associated view.

> NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x608000265480 "UIView:0x7fae6b409dd0.leading">
>
> NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x608000265480 "UIView:0x7fae6b409dd0.trailing">
>
> NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x608000265480 "UIView:0x7fae6b409dd0.top">

Comment: Filter using firstItem & secondItem properties of NSLayoutConstraint class.

Comment: @NareshReddyM How do i get the view from it? first/second item are AnyObject

Comment: Check this thread's first answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045796/enumerating-a-views-nslayoutconstraints-in-swift

Comment: Thanks, constraint.firstItem.isDescendant(of: view1) this worked for me from: http://themainthread.com/blog/2013/05/auto-layout-for-ios-revisited.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `firstItem` and `secondItem` properties of `NSLayoutConstraint` to get the views related to the constraint.  Note that `secondItem` is an *Optional* and must be unwrapped.

Then you can use the `===` operator to compare if it is the same object:

```
let constraints = view1.superview!.constraints
var count = 0

print("superview has \(constraints.count) constraints")

for constraint in constraints {
    if constraint.firstItem === view1 {
        count += 1
        print(constraint)
    } else if let secondItem = constraint.secondItem, secondItem === view1 {
        count += 1
        print(constraint)
    }
}

print("\(count) of them relate to view1")
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to compare if there exists the hash code of the view in the constraint object:

```
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", constraint] containsString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", view.hash]]
```